# CheckBox inside ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, checkbox, asp.net-3.5

How to add checkbox inside the listbox. Where ChechBoxList controls is not good for more records, By using listbox user can easily scroll to choose the item.

Geetha.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is the

[CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28VS.71%29.aspx).

[Newer CheckBoxList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(v=vs.110).aspx)

Pretty nice step-by-step [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20051231223157/http://www.codetoad.com/asp.net/aspnetcontrols12.asp).

Comment: The step-by-step link is broken.

Answer (score 2):

what about [**checkedListBox**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist(VS.71).aspx) ?

```xml
<asp:CheckBoxList id="checkboxlist1" runat="server"> 
         <asp:ListItem>Item 1</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem>Item 2</asp:ListItem>  
         <asp:ListItem>Item 3</asp:ListItem>          
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

To access items on user action

```
void checkboxlist1_Clicked(Object sender, EventArgs e) 
{          
   if (checkBoxList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
   {
       // DoSomething  
   }      
}
```

Comment: That's CheckBoxList, not checkedListBox.

Answer (score -1):

```xml
<ListBox x:Name="targetList" ItemsSource="{Binding}">

<ListBox.ItemTemplate>

<HierarchicalDataTemplate>

<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

<CheckBox>

<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>

</CheckBox>

</StackPanel>

</HierarchicalDataTemplate>

</ListBox.ItemTemplate>

</ListBox>
```

Comment: Original Poster (OP) was asking for ASP.NET solution - please read the question.