# CheckBox inside a listbox in windows form

Tags: c#, .net, windows

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CheckBox inside ListBox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2212390/checkbox-inside-listbox)
>   [How to insert a check box inside a list box in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4896302/how-to-insert-a-check-box-inside-a-list-box-in-c)

I would like to add check-boxes inside a  list-box, in windows from application.

Here is my code:

```
CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
while (dr.Read())
{

    listBox1.Items.Add(String.Format("{0} {1}",cb,dr["Stu_Name"]));
}
```

However, it is not producing intended result.

What i want is a check-box before each column value from the data reader? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**In short:** You need to use the [CheckedListBox Control (Windows Forms)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ss05xx6%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Here is a sample code for Windows forms application:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var items = checkedListBox1.Items;
        items.Add("Perls");
        items.Add("Checked", true);
    }
```